# Multiple wildcards in apt command to specify version

Tags: apt

Given these available versions, how does one install the latest version in the `19.03` branch using wildcards?

```
# apt policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5:20.10.0~3-0~ubuntu-focal
  Version table:
     5:20.10.0~3-0~ubuntu-focal 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-focal 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
```

I have tried below commands (and several related ones using regex), these do not work for me.

```
# apt install docker-ce='19.03*'
E: Version '19.03*' for 'docker-ce' was not found
```

```
# apt install docker-ce='*:19.03*'
E: Version '*:19.03*' for 'docker-ce' was not found
```

Below commands do work, but don't match my needs. I do not want to specify epoch number or the exact version.

```
# apt install docker-ce='5:19.03*'
# apt install docker-ce='*19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-focal'
```

It seems I can't use multiple globs/pattterns to install the latest 19.03 version.
Did I miss something? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a *good* idea, but you could try something using the apt 2.0 [apt-pattern](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-patterns.7.en.html) syntax ex. (untested) `apt install '?and(?exact-name(docker-ce),?version(:19\.03))'`

Comment: Thank you, tested this and some variations, it always tries to install version 20.10. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but might have something to do with epoch number.